# What does the cv::Scalar type mean?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have to find the sum of the elements in a Mat, the sum function of OpenCV returns a cv::Scalar but how should I interpret it ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`cv::Scalar` is used because the image can be multi-channel.
For this reason the the white color is represented as:

```
cv::Scalar(255,255,255);
```

For access a particular element you can simply use `[] operator`:

```
cv::Scalar myWhite(255,255,255);
cout << myWhite[0] << endl;
```

For the sum, each channel will represent the sum of that particular channel.

Comment: So it's just an array wrapper ?

Comment: Exactly, you can see it as an array. Or better as a fixed size vector (size == 4 in case of the Scalar because image usually have 4 channels R G B A).

Comment: So white is (255,255,255,255) instead ;)

Comment: @Micka: actually the default values allows you to not specify that :)

Comment: One more question, is the elements' type calculated automatically or is it always uchar ?